# colorbox - list of links and contents for modal

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Given the following structure:

```
<table class="myTable">

    <tr>
        <td class="block.productgrid.quickview.cell">
            <a class="myLink">My Link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="contentsForColorbox">
                Some contents
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

... where I'd have a several tables 'myTable' like this, 
How can I pair up click on 'myLink' with display of 'contentsForColorbox' in colorbox?

I think I'm close but I'm missing something:

```
$( '.myLink', this).click( function(){
    $.colorbox({
        inline : true,
        'href': $( '.contentsForColorbox') ,
        'width': 500,
        'height': 350
    });
});
```

... as of now if I have 5 tables 5 of 'contentsForColorbox' will show up in the colorbox.
Sigh, too long a day :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the selector used - `$( '.contentsForColorbox')`, it targets all elements with the given class instead you need to find the target relative to the clicked link

```
$( '.myLink', this).click( function(){
    $.colorbox({
        inline : true,
        'href': $(this).closest('table').find('.contentsForColorbox') ,
        'width': 500,
        'height': 350
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QFKZe/)

Comment: i think the word is BINGO! Thanks!